# Increasing only current using LM317

Tags: current, current-limiting, lm317

For the LM317 there is a precision current regulator circuit. This circuit uses an LM317 and only one resistor between the out and adjust pins. The operation of this circuit completely satisfies me, since I do not need to regulate the voltage, but I need more current than 1.5 A.

How do you recommend doing this? In all the suggested circuits there is also a part for voltage regulation, which I do not need; only current is needed.

I have seen proposals for parallel connection of LM317s, but not everyone approves of this, and there is also a part for voltage regulation.

My idea is to use an LM2596-ADJ as a low-loss voltage regulator and after that use an LM317 for current limiting. At the same time, I will place the connection point of the feedback output already behind the LM317 output. But the whole problem is in the maximum current of 1.5 A for the LM317. I need about 2.7 A to charge a battery.

[image: schematic]

UPD: I have seen circuits using PNP and NPN transistors, but there is a voltage adjustment using LM317. I want LM317 to correct current only, and 2596 to control voltage.

UPD2:

Now my diagram looks like this.
[image: new schematic]
I did not buy 2n3906, but I have bc327 and bc557. Perhaps there is a problem with them, or this circuit is not designed for a battery.
According to the recommendations here, I abandoned the lm317.

Now the problem is that I set the voltage at idle, and when I connect the battery, it goes down and the current also becomes less. If I increase the voltage with the trimmer, the current also increases. But as the battery charges, the voltage increases and the current, respectively, also increases. They probably want to reach idle values.

Comment: Why does it need to be a linear LM317 regulator, and what batteries are you charging?

Comment: Is the LM317 already integrated into the circuit so you can't change it? I really don't understand this. If you can change the voltage regulator, why can't you change the LM317?

Comment: why don't you like parallel?

Comment: lm2956 for voltage and lm317 for current:  I can't see any way that that incompletely described collection of parts could work together well.

Comment: "I need about 2.7 A to charge a battery"  only if you're in a hurry - slower charging is otherwise possible.

Comment: @Jasen This depends on the battery's capacity, for one with 54 Ah it will be already really slow. ;-)

Comment: I will answer all questions at once:
lm317 because I don't know any other way. This method works in practice with currents up to 1.5 amperes;

lm 317 doesn't have to be built into the circuit, I'm open to suggestions;

I like the parallel. I haven't tried it, but I've read that it's not a very good option. If the parallel is acceptable, that suits me;

And yes, I understand that slower charging is possible, but due to the fact that Russia is bombing our power plants, we have power cuts all the time.

Comment: Please **do not** clarify your question in comments, add that information by [edit]ing your question. Down here it will be overseen. You might want to take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read some of the [help]. -- Did you consider or even try the common current boosting with a PNP? I think it should work.

Comment: as this is for personal use do a search for "CV CC DC DC" buy one.

Comment: "but I need more current than 1.5 A" Forget about LM317 then, it will melt through the floor. As for battery chargers, they typically work with PWM controlling a MOSFET. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I understand that in the usual version, it will really melt the floor. That's why I asked this question. But I understood the idea, I'll see what can be done, the electronics store is nearby. :)

Comment: when it goes into current limit the voltage regulator stops dropping the voltage. you get maximum heat.

Comment: @Jasen, are you talking about the consequences of connecting feedback in this way?

Comment: yes. it works, but it works badly.

Comment: @EdinFifić, thanks. One of the reasons I want to assemble the circuit myself is to distract myself. Psychologists say that a hobby can help take your mind off problems. That's why I took up this issue. )

Comment: @EdinFifić As much as I sympathise as well, this comment field is not really the place for these kind of discussions. Please keep it on topic. As for helping out interactively, the [main chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) is probably a good place for that.

Comment: @Lundin My apologies, thank you for reminding me. I wanted to show some encouragement, support and understanding for Deltinos, but this is not the place.
I have deleted those comments.

Comment: I'd kindly recommend that you open a new question with the new circuit and the new problem, linking to this one as reference.

Answer (score 3):

Add a PNP transistor or other voltage detector into the output to feed current to the FB node when the current hits the limit. In this way the switched-mode regulator chip will throttle back when the current limit activates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc5fpo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Didn't you misplace the output freewheeling diode? It goes right next to the OUT pin. Also, let him know he needs at least a 2W resistor or a combination of resistors, due to the power dissipation across it (the R1). Plus large input and output capacitors (min. 220uF in, 470uF out, low ESR).

Comment: I sure did! thank you.

Comment: @Jasen, in general, this circuit resembles a typical circuit for xl4015 or xl2596, except for the transistor and resistor that are added.

How to calculate the current in this circuit?

Comment: @Deltinos The current is calculated by taking into account that 0.6V is needed across the base-emitter junction for the transistor to conduct.

Comment: @Deltinos No need to worry about the voltage accuracy: the current limit takes priority until it's close to full charge, then the increasing voltage on the battery will automatically keep reducing current as it will be close to the output voltage from the inductor, which will keep reducing voltage error until almost zero error when the battery is full.

Comment: @Deltinos Either way, the voltage set by the resistor divider R2/R3 will not be exceeded.

Comment: @EdinFifić, Later I will try to simulate this circuit and find out the value of R1 experimentally, since the principle of calculation is still not clear to me. Probably, I have moved away from electronics for too long, although even before that I had not super knowledge.

Comment: @Deltinos R1 turns on Q1 when the voltage across R1 is approximately the VBE voltage of Q1. At the current limit, the voltage on R1 will be somewhere between 0.6 to 0.7V, depending on the parallel resistance R2||R3. The lower the R2||R3, the higher the voltage across R1 has to be to start cutting down the feedback, but it's not a large range. You can trivially experimentally test this. Spice simulations will also work - replace the switching regulator with a simple op-amp based linear regulator, whose feedback network you'll be affecting.

Comment: @Deltinos It's easy, just divide 0.6V with the resistor value to get the current. The value indicated in the schematic should allow between 1.5A and 2A. For about 3A, you could use around 200mΩ or 0.2Ω. LM2596 shouldn't go above that.

Comment: @EdinFifić, I deleted one of my comments when the thought came to just try to apply Ohm's law, because regulation is secondary, as I understand it. First of all, the current simply flows through the resistor. And I came to this meaning. Thank you!

Comment: @EdinFifić this solution doesn't work.

If without these additions, the standard circuit 2596 - everything turns out, but without current control.

If I add a resistor and a transistor, the voltage just can't go up. At the same time, as the battery is charged, it increases, and the current also increases.

Answer (score 1):

The LM317 is more than you need, yet not enough. It has a high overhead voltage so will have a lot of loss, and it’s limited to 1.5A.

A simple current limiter can be constructed from two NPN transistors, which will have much less overhead (only a half a volt or so) and can be scaled up to high current by choosing an appropriate pass NPN.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll think about it, look for an example circuit, and try if necessary! For now, I'll try the above diagram.

Answer (score 1):

National Semiconductor has other 3-terminal regulators with higher current ratings.

LM350 - 3 A

LN338 - 5 A

Comment: Thanks, I've been thinking about them.
It is even possible to order them. This is the easy way. I'll see what works best. Logically, PWM is indeed more correct.